# how to import datasets one by one from a given list into a function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of such datasets.
here are the list of datasets

```
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3E3B
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3OLS3B
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_4B4E
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_4OS4E
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_4S4OS
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_OLS
```

an example of the contents of such a dataset

```
structure(list(x1 = c(2032L, 2204L, 2204L, 1861L, 1861L, 1562L, 
1562L, 2218L, 2218L, 815L, 348L, 471L, 753L, 608L, 948L, 98L, 
39L, 836L), x2 = c(1898L, 2586L, 2924L, 2564L, 1962L, 1758L, 
1594L, 2276L, 2198L, 14L, 748L, 287L, 508L, 223L, 796L, 318L, 
371L, 727L), x3 = c(2320L, 2353L, 2353L, 2023L, 2023L, 1732L, 
1732L, 2432L, 2432L, 516L, 351L, 371L, 720L, 872L, 679L, 703L, 
674L, 514L), x4 = c(2183L, 2134L, 2134L, 2053L, 2053L, 2053L, 
2053L, 2684L, 2684L, 531L, 551L, 1L, 572L, 97L, 654L, 274L, 115L, 
436L), x5 = c(989L, 1058L, 1058L, 984L, 984L, 933L, 933L, 1070L, 
1070L, 319L, 519L, 525L, 843L, 994L, 220L, 650L, 347L, 150L), 
    x6 = c(418L, 476L, 476L, 451L, 451L, 437L, 437L, 443L, 443L, 
    966L, 661L, 844L, 588L, 389L, 537L, 983L, 516L, 137L), x7 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

I use this fucntion

```
 data.table::setDT(any dataset)

get_binary_mirror <- function(val,N,prop=0.9) {
  val=as.integer(val)
  m_x = rep(val,times=floor(prop*N))
  # add opposite type the number of times of the difference in length
  m_x = c(m_x, rep(0^val, times = N-length(m_x)))
  sample(m_x)
}


any dataset[, class1:=get_binary_mirror(.BY, .N), by=class]
fwrite(any dataset,"any dataset.csv")
```

For each dataset i must everytime new dataset manually paste. For example

```
  data.table::setDT(dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3E3B)
then  
   data.table::setDT(dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3E3B)
```

and so on.
Is there a way that all datasets automatically work through this function so that I do not manually insert each dataset individually?

Ideally, I need, firstly, each dataset from the list to work automatically in this function, so that I don’t change the input datasets by hand, and after processing, each dataset is written to the csv with its own name. For example

```
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3E3B.csv
dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3OLS3B.csv
```

and so on.
How can it be done?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to make a string list of the names (only using the first two datasets for now):

```
ds_names <- c("dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3E3B", "dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3OLS3B")
```

Then, put your datasets in a list (using shorter variable names than your original dt_spring_B_3B3OSvsdt_spring_B_3E3B, etc.)

```
dss <- list(ds1, ds2)
```

Name these list-elements with the string names above:

```
names(dss) <- ds_names
```

Now apply function over all datasets, looping through the names:

```
sapply(ds_names, function(dsname) {
  ds <- dss[[dsname]]     # get the dataset with name from argument

  # do whatever you need to do with this dataset
  dst <- data.table::setDT(ds)
  data.table::fwrite(dst, paste0(dsname, ".csv"))    # write to file using the name from argument

  TRUE
})
```